# Vertically bottom-align an image in a table with variable cell-heights

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, adjustbox

I have a problem vertically aligning an image with `\adjustimage` from the [adjustbox-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) in a table. I am creating many tables automatically and they have the same layout of one X column with a text of variable length, then some short columns inbetween and the last column has an image with a small height. This image should always be aligned to the bottom of the cell.

The problem seems to be the first X column, because sometimes the text fits in one line and sometimes it breaks into two lines and I cannot find a way to always fit the image to the bottom line of the X-column regardless of the number of lines in this cell.

Because I don't know the length of the text in the X-column beforehand I am looking for a solution, which works regardless of the textlength.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{X r r p{50mm}}
\hline
here is some text over two lines & N & M & \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
one line text & N & M & \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{X r r p{50mm}}
\hline
here is some text over two lines & N & M &\mbox{}\newline \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
one line text & N & M & \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\vskip1cm

\bgroup
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}b{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{X r r p{50mm}}
\hline
here is some text over two lines & N & M & \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
one line text & N & M & \adjustimage{width = 50mm, height = 2mm}{example-image}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can't use your first solution, because it uses different code in the two lines, but your second solution works for me. It changes the alignement of the middle columns as well, but this is not a problem in my case. It seems your second solution redefines the X-column. Can you explain why it works?

Comment: I simply used the way indicated p. 3 of tabularx  documentation. As you probably know, `b{some length}` is a column type like `p{some length}`,  but bottom-aligned. The example I refer to  redefines it as `m`, which can be used for a contents vertically centred  in cells.